# JUNIT test - Eclipse IDE is throwing an error

Tags: java, junit

I have the class and method below and I am trying to get JUNIT testing to work but it is throwing an error.  Here is the class

```
package christmas;

public class Worksheet1q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 3, n = 4;
        int result = power(m, n);
        System.out.printf( "power method  ");
        System.out.printf( "%d^%d = %d", m, n, result);


    } 

    //* code for  power

static int power(int m, int n) {



    if (n != 0)



        return (m * power(m, n - 1));
    else


 }}
```

and here is my JUNIT test class and method.

```
  package christmas;


  import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

  import org.junit.Test;



  public class Worksheet1q1Test {

    @Test


    public void twoAndThreeissix(int m, int n) throws Exception {




    int result = Worksheet1.power(2, 3);

    assertThat(result, is(8L));

    }}
```

I have 2 issues.  Firstly when I run the Test class I have an error that method 'christmas cannot be found' but christmas is my package name so not sure why Eclipse thinks it is a method

Plus I am getting an error on assertThat - the error is suggesting that the method 'is' cannot be found.

This is my first attempt at JUNIT testing so any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: result is an int and you are comparing to a Long

Comment: *the error is suggesting that the method 'is' cannot be found* you never import `is`. http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#is(T)

Comment: You're missing `import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;`

Comment: also I would just assertEquals(result, 8)

Comment: thank you - very helpful but I still cannot get around why eclipse thinks that my package Christmas is a method

Comment: I don't think we can help you with why eclipse thinks christmas is a method. You may want to upload some screenshot for that.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code, and fixed the errors as they game up. I ran it on command line. I've put all the things that gave errors into comments:

```
package christmas;

public class Worksheet1q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 3, n = 4;
        int result = power(m, n);
        System.out.printf( "power method  ");
        System.out.printf( "%d^%d = %d", m, n, result);
    } 

    //* code for  power
    static int power(int m, int n) {
      if (n != 0)
        return (m * power(m, n - 1));
      else return 1;    // added due to below error
    }                   // compile error, illegal start of statement.
}
```

For the test I added a test that doesn't fail with an `int` instead of a `long`:

```
package christmas;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is; //  error: cannot find symbol

// compiler: warning: [deprecation] <T>assertThat(T,Matcher<? super T>) in Assert has been deprecated
// import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

public class Worksheet1q1Test {

    @Test
    // FAILURES!!!  Method twoAndThreeIsEightLong should have no parameters
//    public void twoAndThreeIsEightLong(int m, int n) throws Exception {
    public void twoAndThreeIsEightLong() throws Exception {
//      int result = Worksheet1.power(2, 3); // error: cannot find symbol
      int result = Worksheet1q1.power(2, 3);
      assertThat(result, is(8L));  // result is an int - will fail!
    }

    @Test
    public void twoAndThreeIsEightInt() throws Exception {
      int result = Worksheet1q1.power(2, 3);
      assertThat(result, is(8));
    }

    @Test
    public void twoAndThreeIsEight() throws Exception {
      int result = Worksheet1q1.power(2, 3);
      assertEquals(result, 8);
    }
}
```

Compiling:

```
javac -cp C:\..snip..\lib\junit-4.13.jar;C:\..snip..\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;target -d target src/christmas/*.java
```

Running:

```
java -cp C:\..snip..\lib\junit-4.13.jar;C:\..snip..\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;target org.junit.runner.JUnitCore christmas.Worksheet1q1Test
```

Result:

```
JUnit version 4.13
...E
Time: 0.042
There was 1 failure:
1) twoAndThreeIsEightLong(christmas.Worksheet1q1Test)
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected: is <8L>
     but: was <8>
        at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:964)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:930)
        at christmas.Worksheet1q1Test.twoAndThreeIsEightLong(Worksheet1q1Test.java:18)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 3,  Failures: 1
```

Comment: Thank you - your help is very much appreciated together with others,

Comment: @Sharp I added a test that uses `assertEquals(result, 8);` too. It also needs the extra import.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not good.

This works fine in IntelliJ:

```
package christmas;

public class Worksheet1q1 {

    public static final int DEFAULT_BASE = 3;
    public static final int DEFAULT_EXPONENT = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = (args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : DEFAULT_BASE);
        int n = (args.length > 1 ? Integer.parseInt(args[1]) : DEFAULT_EXPONENT);
        int result = power(m, n);
        System.out.printf("%d^%d = %d", m, n, result);
    }

    static int power(int m, int n) {
        if (n < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative powers are not allowed");
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return (m * power(m, n - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

I'll write the unit test next:

```
package christmas;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Worksheet1q1Test {

    @Test
    public void testPower_Success() {
        // setup
        int m = 2;
        int n = 3;
        int expected = 8;
        // exercise
        int actual = Worksheet1q1.power(m, n);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPower_ZeroPower() {
        // setup
        int m = 2;
        int n = 0;
        int expected = 1;
        // exercise
        int actual = Worksheet1q1.power(m, n);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testPower_NegativePower() {
        // setup
        int m = 2;
        int n = -3;
        int expected = 1;
        // exercise
        Worksheet1q1.power(m, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Helpful?  It's the right answer.  Are you Tom Sawyering me?  Is this homework?

Comment: this is not homework - this is me an experienced IT pro trying to learn new skills.  Now I have something that works I can play with this and adapt it for other projects....

Comment: Can't imagine why this was downvoted.  The original code was not correct; this code corrects it.  The empty else was clearly wrong.  The unit test is an improvement as well. Why the downvote?

Comment: I agree this has been incredibly helpful - don't know why it was downgraded.  I am a Cisco engineer and trying to learn coding after all these years I forgot how hard it was to get into the basics and build from there.  Most websites and videos never seem to start in the right place, you need someone to help with something that you are struggling to work.  And the people on the thread helped me do that.  IO have now written six Junit tests of my own - I am flying - thank you.

Comment: Great job.  You can learn OOP, Java and TDD if you can master Cisco and networking.  Post back if you need more.